# Which of these algorithms are more efficient in big-θ notation?

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AiH1r.png)

```
procedure MatchExistsA
   for i = 2 to n
     for j = 1 to i-1
       if a_j = a_i then return true
   return false

procedure MatchExistsB
 BubbleSort(list)
   for i = 1 to n-1
     if a_i == a_i+1 then return true
   return false
```

I calculated the worst-case running time of each algorithm using Θ notation, and for the first algorithm, I got Θ(n²).

When i=2, there is 1 iteration in the inner loop. When i=3, there are 2, and so on. At i=n, there are n-1 iterations. Thus, the total is 1+2+...+n-1 => n(n-1)/2 => Θ(n²)

For the second one, the question assumes BubbleSort has Θ(n²) at worst-case. The loop then has n-1 iterations i.e. Θ(n). Thus, max ( Θ(n²) , Θ(n) ) = Θ(n²).

It is right that both of them have the same running time? I feel like I'm doing something wrong or I am not understanding the question correctly.

Comment: Evil - The questions wants the answer is big-Theta notation.

Comment: Probably [task from here](https://www.coursehero.com/file/p1hvcbc/We-continue-testing-one-half-at-a-time-until-we-reduce-our-search-range-down-to/), yes indeed asks about Theta. Still very odd. Bubble sort is $\Omega(n)$ and $\mathcal O(n^2)$, to my best knowledge saying it is $\Theta(n^2)$ is a mistake.

Comment: @Evil - Actually you are right about BubbleSort. However, the BubbleSort written here is based on some slides provided. I was told that there are good and bad BubbleSort. The BubbleSort algorithm provided in our slide is indeed n^2 for both best and worst.

Comment: @Evil The most simple change that would make Θ(n²) correct would be _worst case_ (which may or may not have been implied).

Comment: @greybeard I see, it would make perfect sense now - saying that the bound is tight. I understood it was about algorithms runtime, so it was a bit off.

Comment: "both of them have the same running time" -- no. The same $\Theta$-bounds do not imply equality of the running-time functions.